# Django:How password store in django auth_user table

Tags: python, django

I am customizing the django user module and adding some extra fields

my model is looking like

```
class Drinker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    name     = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is my register view

```
def DrinkerRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create(username = form.cleaned_data['username'],email = form.cleaned_data['email'],password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            drinker = Drinker(name = form.cleaned_data['name'],birthday = form.cleaned_data['birthday'],user=user)
            drinker.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('register.html',context,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Now my question is when the user is registering in my auth_user table the password is storing in plan text  i.e causing

```
Unknown password hashing algorithm '123'. Did you specify it in the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?
```

error at the time of login

but for superusers passwords are in SHA1 format (i am not sure )  in auth_user table and they are able to login

please suggest me how to  hash the password field here?

Comment: what happens if you try to store legal input in a Drinker model directly in the shell? Does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `User.objects.create()`, use [`User.objects.create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) - it will hash provided password using correct algorithm.

Comment: yeah got it thanks   and one more think  do i need to use PASSWORD_HASHERS  in my settings

Comment: No, as long as you don't have existing user database with different password hashing algorithm than your Django version's default (which for current release - 1.4 - is PBKDF2). If you'll be just creating new users, you're fine with default setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should let User.set_password hash the password and store it in the appropriate format, or use the appropriate manager function as mentioned in the other answer.

Basically you never asked Django to hash the password and tried to put the plain text in your database. In doing so, the format (hasher salt hashed_pass) that Django expected was not met hence the error.

Better yet, those parts of your app are best done using reusable apps such as Django Registration.

You can then use signals to create the Drinker profile after an user registers (is created).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`create_user()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#creating-users) helper function, which will set the password correctly.